# Jquery animate div and return function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

When I click in my menubar, I have a div going down from the top. I need to make a function that upon the button link being clicked again it returns to the top. This is what I have tried so far:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper"><button id="top">&raquo;</button></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#top").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "+=300px"}, "slow");
});
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#abc;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin-top:5px;
}

#wrapper {

    top: 80px;
 }  


.block {
     margin-top:-95px;
  }   
​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FjqYU/1/)

Comment: Please include your code within your question as well. If jsfiddle goes down your question will be of little use to others in the future.

Comment: There's a very neat [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function made for this kind of thing.

Comment: But that isn't what the OP is looking for.  Rather that the block animates into view, instead of being rolled out.  I like Josh's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#top").on('click', function(){
    var elm = $(".block");
    elm.animate({"top": ((parseInt(elm.css('top'), 10)>10?"-=":"+=")+"300px")}, "slow");
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6eLz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using jquery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Your code would look something like this:

```
$("#top").toggle(function(){
    $(".block").animate({"top": "+=300px"}, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(".block").animate({"top": "-=300px"}, "slow");
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FjqYU/6/)

Since it appears that [toggle() is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/), here is another solution that uses click:

```
$("#top").on("click", function(){
    if(!$(".block").hasClass('down'))
        $(".block").addClass('down').animate({"top": "+=300px"}, "slow");
    else
        $(".block").animate({"top": "-=300px"}, "slow").removeClass('down');
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FjqYU/10/)

Comment: Thats good to know. Would you happen to know what has replaced it?

Comment: Do you have any reference to it being deprecated? I do not see it mentioned in the documentation for it on jquery's site?

Answer (score 0):

hello you can do it like this just assign it diff. classes in diff. situation and your work will be done

```
$("#top").click(function(){
  if($(".block").hasClass('Down')==false && $(".block").hasClass('Stop')==false)
  {
    $(".block").animate({"top": "+=300px"}, "slow").addClass('Down');
  }
  else
  {
        $(".block").animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow").removeClass('Down').addClass('Stop');
  }

});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FjqYU/5/)

Comment: Your demo breaks after you have clicked it twice.